# Parameters types passed to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures

I am implementing a SQL to LINQ service, and I want to call a stored procedure, defined as follows:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTransportationOffers] 
    @pickupLocID int = 0, 
    @destinationLocID int = 0,
    @serviceDateTime dateTime,
    @isAsInstructed bit = 0
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT       
      TransportationServices.id AS ServiceID, TransportationVehicles.id AS VehicleID, 
      TransportationServices.ClientPrice, 
      TransportationServices.Currency, TransportationVehicles.Description, 
      TransportationVehicles.Image, TransportationVehicles.MaxPassengers,
      CASE
         WHEN (DATEDIFF(hour, @serviceDateTime, GETDATE()) > Suppliers.MinNoticeHours) 
           THEN 'auto-service' 
         ELSE
           'no auto-service'
      END 
   FROM            
      TransportationServices 
   INNER JOIN
      TransportationVehicles ON TransportationServices.VehicleID = TransportationVehicles.id  
   INNER JOIN
      Suppliers ON TransportationServices.SupplierID = Suppliers.id
   WHERE        
      (TransportationServices.PickupLocationID = @pickupLocID) 
      AND ((TransportationServices.DropoffLocationID = @destinationLocID) OR
           ((TransportationServices.DropoffLocationID = NULL) AND (@isAsInstructed = 1)))
```

The signature generated for the interface function is as follows:

```
GetTransportationOffers (System.Int32 pickupLocID, System.Int32 destinationLocID, System.DateTime serviceDateTime, System.Boolean isAsInstructed)
```

Calling this function gives me the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

None of the parameters in the stored procedure or in the auto-generated interface function are Strings. When I run the stored procedure using the SQL Studio, there I get no exception. Could there be a problem interpreting the boolean parameter? The datetime parameter? Is something happening inside the stored procedure?

**MORE**

For the record, the DB is MS SQL Server.
Having added a "printf" or a log entry to the SPROC, I can say that LINQ to SQL calls the SPROC with the correct parameters. Also, the SPROC now has a TRY/CATCH clause which doesn't indicate an exception within the SPROC, so I have to conclude that the problem is on the return trip. What is getting screwed up in converting the table returned by the SPROC to the

Comment: What **database** is this for?? SQL is just the query language - used by many databases..... I think you should **not** use `= NULL` to check for null - use `IS NULL` instead: `TransportationServices.DropoffLocationID IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

If I explain it to myself slowly enough, I can figure out the answer...

The last column in the SELECT statement was a CASE statement without an AS clause, and therefore had no column name.  Adding such a clause helped the LINQ to SQL interface understand the result, and just like that, it worked!